# warning: could not load any Objective-C class information

Tags: swift

I'm creating a hangman app. So I've get this error on a variable called words of my subclass: Normal. Error:

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

Unfortunately, more people have this question and can't seem to answer it. I've tried initialising the variable words within the class but it didn't work. Hopefully someone can provide me with some feedback on how to solve this issue. Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // ********  LOCAL VARIABLES *********
    var evulMode = true
    let someMode = Mode()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func input(sender: UITextField) {
        let input = sender.text!

        someMode.hangMan(letter: input)
    }

    // Framework for the hangman game. Calls two modes: normal or evul.
    class Mode {

        var evulMode = false
        var normal = Normal()
        var inProgress = false

        func hangMan(letter: String) {
            if evulMode == true {
                print(letter)
            } else {
                normal.check(letter: letter)
            }
        }
    }

    // Evul mode

    // Normale mode
    class Normal: Mode {
        var words: [String] = []

        override init() {
            words = ["peach", "apple", "banana"]
        }

        func computeWord() -> String.CharacterView {
            let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(words.count)))
            let word: String = words[randomIndex]
            let arrayWord = word.characters
            return(arrayWord)
        }

        func check(letter: String) {
            if (inProgress == false) {
                print("inProgess = false")
                let word = Array(computeWord())
                print(word)
                inProgress = true
            }
        }
        //for (index, element) in word.enumerate() {
        //print("Item \(index): \(element)")
        //}
    }

    // Houdt de staat van de game bij.
    class UserState {
        let word = []
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Which Swift version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I only see one thing wrong. The **`UserState`** class as an invalid property. The **`word`** should have an explicit type. You can't have an empty collection literal. It always requires an explicit type.

So, give him a type:

```
class UserState {
    let word: [String] = [] //or let word = [String]()
}
```

Even so, I don't see why do you need an immutable property when the class has no initializers.